# React - Allow user to add file from gallery or camera

Tags: reactjs, mobile, camera, gallery

I have a react-redux site which allows user to drag and drop files from file system,
now I want to let them do the same on mobile-
add a screenshot from camera, or file from gallery.

For the drag & drop on desktop I'm using the [react-dropzone package](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone).

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code from there documentation:
It allows user to click on the DropZone and opens a file picker:

```
class Basic extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      disabled: true,
      files: []
    }
  }
​
  onDrop(files) {
    this.setState({files});
  }
​
  toggleDisabled() {
    this.setState({
      disabled: !this.state.disabled
    })
  }
​
  render() {
    const files = this.state.files.map(file => (
      <li key={file.name}>
        {file.name} - {file.size} bytes
      </li>
    ))
​
    return (
      <section>
        <aside>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={this.toggleDisabled.bind(this)}
          >
            Toggle disabled
          </button>
        </aside>
        <div className="dropzone">
          <Dropzone
            onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
          >
            {({getRootProps, getInputProps}) => (
              <div {...getRootProps()}>
                <input {...getInputProps()} />
                 <p>Drop files here, or click to select files</p>
              </div>
            )}
          </Dropzone>
        </div>
        <aside>
          <h4>Files</h4>
          <ul>{files}</ul>
        </aside>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
​
<Basic />
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to use this somponent- but it's not working for me on mobile, and this is what I asked for

Comment: you are right, the problem was with my server side code for file upload, not the react-dropzone problem. so this question can be closed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is that react-dropzone does works well (as of [harish soni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6457067/harish-soni)'s answer)
but it depends on the mobile version:
react-dropzone makes using of 'input type="file"' html element which is not supported by **all** mobile devices.

for better mobile support understanding refer [here](https://viljamis.com/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the React-Dropzone package that you're using for both:

The solution to supporting mobile was shown on Github here:
https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/issues/1196

The key is to use the noClick property and then manually add a onClick listener.

See documentation: https://react-dropzone.js.org/

I have made an example of how the fix works:

```html
import { useDropzone } from 'react-dropzone';

const { getInputProps, isDragAccept, isDragReject, getRootProps, open } = useDropzone({ noClick: true}}
<div
   {...getRootProps({
     className: clsx('dropzone-container', `dropzone-border-${getBorderColor()}`),
   })}
   onClick={open} >
   <input {...getInputProps()} />
   <Icon name="cloud upload" size="big" className="dropzone-icon" />
   <p>Drag 'n' drop your images here, or click to select them.</p>
 </div
```